# mb_ereg_replaceについて

Tags: php, 正規表現

**mb_ereg_replaceは、[正規表現](http://php.net/manual/ja/refs.basic.text.php)のページに掲載されていなくて、[マルチバイト文字列](http://php.net/manual/ja/book.mbstring.php)に掲載されているのですが、正規表現としてはどういう位置付けになるのですか？**
・PCRE でもなく、POSIXでもない？？

---

**preg_replaceの方がmb_ereg_replaceより良い点はありますか？**
・どういう風に使い分けるのですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***・PCRE でもなく、POSIXでもない？？***

ネーミングだけから言えば、昔のPHP用のPOSIX拡張系正規表現の`ereg_replace`のマルチバイト対応版です。ただし、通常の正規表現の実装でPOSIX拡張正規表現として規定されていることしかできないということはまずありませんので、「POSIXでない」なんて判定できるのかどうかはわかりません。「PCREでない」のは間違いないです。

***・どういう風に使い分けるのですか？***

特に使い分ける必要はなく、「日本語扱うんなら`mb_`系の方が良いんじゃね?」的に決められても問題はないと思います。要件的に「使えない」場合を外した後、お好きな方を使えば良いでしょう。

- PCREはコアモジュールなのでPHPが使えるなら必ず使える

  環境によっては`mb_ereg_replace`を含むmbstring拡張モジュールは有効になっていないかもしれません。環境設定を自分でいじれないなら、PCREを使わざるを得ないかもしれません。
- PCREはUTF-8以外のマルチバイトエンコーディングは扱えない

  別項に書いたように、UTF-8がメモリの中でどんなバイト列になっているか把握していて、その上でそのバイト列に対しての操作を行うので無い限り、PCREはUTF-8以外には使えません。

Comment: ereg_replaceはPHP7では削除されて、マルチバイト対応版であるmb_ereg_replaceが利用可能なのはなぜですか？　ereg_replaceが PHP 7 で 削除 されたのは、マルチバイト対応ではなかったから？？

Comment: `mb_ereg_replace`は名前だけ`ereg_replace`から借りていますが、中身的には全く別の実装です。`ereg_replace`はPHP 5.3以降非推奨になっていたわけですが、大きな理由は「バイナリセーフではない」ことです。"ereg バイナリセーフ"あたりで検索すると具体例のある解説記事が出てきますが、例えば"\x0"(NUL文字)が含まれる文字列に対して期待通りの結果にならず、脆弱性の原因になるといった問題点があるためです。「マルチバイト対応ではない」と言うのは間接的動機ではあったかもしれませんが、直接問題視されたわけではないようです。

Comment: mb_ereg_replace と ereg_replace では、実装が異なるのですね。名前が似ていたので、同じ実装のマルチバイト対応版だと勘違いしていました